# Python documentation in PyCharm IDE

Tags: pycharm

I'm having trouble accessing Python documentation from within PyCharm. I tried `View | Quick Documentation` and it says `No Documentation Found`. Is there any easy way I can configure this to show the documentation?

To clarify, I'm looking for Python documentation i.e description of the functions/features of the inbuilt libraries, not documentation about PyCharm itself.

Answer (score 2):

Simply highlight the module you are interested in (either in the editor or under *External Libraries* folder) and press CTRL+Q.

Normally an external link do the official documentation is displayed. Sometimes even some basic description of the module is available right in the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Usually highlighting the module and pressing Ctrl+Q would work for modules/classes/objects/functions in the standard libraries. You may also try to invoke "help" in the python console, especially if what you want to retrieve is something you need to import first. For example, to get the documentation of the "Workbook", you could type help(openpyxl.Workbook) to learn the details, which simply pressing Ctrl+Q would respond No Documentation Found instead.